# Running multiple SQL queries on a single CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

**Use case:**
A database table tracks cars on a lot.  Each car must be inspected every three months.  When I pull a list of cars to inspect, I also want to update their [Status] to reflect that.  This can be done by using a temp table, but a common table expression would execute faster and make more sense if it could be used this way.

**Attempted solution:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM [dbo].[CarInventory]
    WHERE <car requires inspection> )

SELECT ID
    FROM CTE;

UPDATE [dbo].[CarInventory]
    SET Status = 'Queued for inspection'
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE);
```

The SELECT statement would run but I cannot find a way to use the CTE in the subsequent UPDATE statement.  Is there some way to perform the SELECT and UPDATE using a CTE so I don't have to create a temp table?

Thanks!

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: The CTE is an "ad-hoc" view that's available for **one, subsequent** statement. There's nothing that can change that. If you need to run multiple statements on the result set of the CTE, store those results into a temporary table (or a table variable, in SQL Server - if that's what you're using)

Comment: You can't use a CTE for multiple queries. You can create a temp table and store inside it the data from CTE. For this particular example, if you are in TSQL (didn't mentioned the dbms), you can include in update, OUTPUT inserted.ID so you can get the ids updated.

Comment: Skip the cte, create a view instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it.  Why are you selecting the `id`s?  Just do:

```
UPDATE ci
    SET Status = 'Queued for inspection'
    FROM [dbo].[CarInventory] ci;
    WHERE <car requires inspection> ;
```

If you want to return the `id`s that are affected, use an [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

Answer (score 0):

By Inner Joining the CTE with the table that you want to update you will only update those joined records.

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (
    SELECT ID
    FROM [dbo].[CarInventory]
    WHERE <car requires inspection>  
    )

UPDATE [dbo].[CarInventory]
    SET Status = 'Queued for inspection'
    OUTPut CTE.*
FROM [dbo].[CarInventory]
INNER JOIN CTE ON [dbo].[CarInventory].ID = cte.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output clause of the update statement to get the list after the update.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I was simply barking up the wrong tree by using CTE in the first place.  Thank you for setting me straight!  Also, sorry to leave you guessing on software; I was using SSMS.

Using the OUTPUT clause recommended by Joe and Ryan to update a table and also view the affected records worked.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[CarInventory]
SET Status = 'Queued for inspection'
OUTPUT Deleted.ID
WHERE <car requires inspection>
```

I briefly poked at the VIEW mechanic that jarlh suggested.  It looks like a bit more work than OUTPUT for this instance but I'm inspired to learn all about it now.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you already have an answer with the same code, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers